# How do I access to element each by each from firebase

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I get the user id's which is not contains a specific word. I need to pick for each user id for update user status.

```
var primeusers = [];
var komence= firebase.database().ref();

function thisclick() {


    komence.child('Buyers').on("value", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(data) {


       if(!data.val().Nealdi.includes("GPA")) {

    console.log(data.key);
    primeusers = data.key;
}


    });
});


}
```

By using this code I get the user id's.Console log :

```
7SlLam2k0P1grrdggw3JFAaSNyt1 
677nl6n0D6563jPfbWGn2dJfI0X2 
We67878jtdaJ0dkkHLSThXODwOA3 
fpZzOcbeawg3VcWQnOZ6PlWhxmP2 
zwJgnxsamkSsz720jDHrtZsdsaR2
```

When I try to pick second object I use `console.log(primeusers[1]);` But I get the second character of each value.

Console output :

```
S
7
e
p
W
```

But this not what I need. How do I get the whole second line?

Comment: primeusers is a string not an array. You are getting 2nd letter of the string.

Comment: Actually i use var primeusers = []; update code.

Comment: Now you need to push into the array with primeusers.push(data.key) please see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want `primeusers` to be an array, right now it's a string - that's why you get the second character when doing `primeusers[1]`.

```
var primeusers = [];
```

Will turn primeusers into an array.

```
primeusers.push(data.key);
```

Adds their id to the primeusers array.

Script including those changes:

```
var primeusers = [];
var komence= firebase.database().ref();

function thisclick() {
    komence.child('Buyers').on("value", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
       if(!data.val().Nealdi.includes("GPA")) {
         primeusers.push(data.key);
       }
    });
    console.log(primeusers[1]); //this should log the entire second id
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare an array `primeusers=[]` and then push values into that array with `primeusers.push(data.key)`.

```
var primeusers=[];
var komence= firebase.database().ref();

function thisclick(){    
 komence.child('Buyers').on("value",function(snapshot){
  snapshot.forEach(function(data){
   if(!data.val().Nealdi.includes("GPA")){
    console.log(data.key);
    primeusers.push(data.key);
   }
  });
 });
}
```